# delete every occurrence of text between parenthesis except if it contains 4 digits

Tags: bash

I want to remove every occurrence of text between parenthesis except if it contains 4 digits.

source:

```
var="7 Days (TEXT) (some.other.text) (10%) (May contain 1000) (2003)"
```

desired output:

```
7 Days (2003)
```

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: @Marc Towler also tested in pure bash, but it fail if an other parenthesis contain a digit: `shopt -s extglob; var=${var//(*[^0-9][^0-9][^0-9][^0-9])/}; shopt -u extglob`

Comment: If you are hooked on AWK, you can try fooling around with the following:

awk 'STR1=match ($0, /^[^(]*/) {print substr($0, RSTART, RLENGTH)}; STR2=match($0, /\([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]\)/) {print substr($0, RSTART, RLENGTH)} '

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ echo "$var" | sed 's/([^)]*[^[:digit:]()][^)]*)//g; s/([^)]\{0,3\})//g; s/([^)]\{5,\})//g'
7 Days     (2003)
```

How it works:

- `s/([^)]*[^[:digit:]()][^)]*)//g`

  This removes any parenthesized expression that has a non-digit in it.
- `s/([^)]\{0,3\})//g`

  This removes any parenthesized expression that has 3 or fewer characters in it.
- `s/([^)]\{5,\})//g`

  This removes any parenthesized expression that has 5 or more characters in it.

Comment: Many thanks, if i only use `s/([^)]*[^[:digit:]()][^)]*)//g` it work for my example, do you think i really need the two others sed match ?

Comment: understood! `var="7 Days (123) (12345) (TEXT) (some.other.text) (10%) (May contain 1000) (2003)"` added to your solution another match to remove extra space `sed 's/([^)]*[^[:digit:]()][^)]*)//g; s/([^)]\{0,3\})//g; s/([^)]\{5,\})//g; s/  */ /g;'` regards.

Comment: Very good.  And, yes, that is a good way to remove excess blanks.